# html mobile number range pattern definition

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

The user signs up and enters mobile number, which must be of the proper format written (e.g countey code should be included) 
the proper number that is acceptable is:  `+16174552211`
here is the input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" pattern="[+][0-9]{1,10}" placeholder="+16174552211">
```

What it does is, verifies the number starting with plus sign followed by 10 exact digits, but i need to define a range so that user can enter numbers lets say from 10 to 12, how is that possible with this pattern?

Comment: [`\+[0-9]{10,12}`](https://regex101.com/r/fG4aS1/2)

Comment: @Uchiha  Suggestion: `[+]` => `\+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" pattern="\+[0-9]{10,12}" placeholder="+16174552211">
```